# Jenkins not recognizing file path for pom.xml

Tags: maven, jenkins

I have file path as /Users/xxx/Documents/WorkSpace/project-test/pom.xml
Under root POM I have given the same path which I got for terminal.

I get following error on Jenkins
ERROR: No such file /Users/xxx/Documents/WorkSpace/project-test/pom.xml
Perhaps you need to specify the correct POM file path in the project configuration?
I am using Mac High Sierra.

Comment: I assume you are using a pipeline with Jenkinsfile? If so have you defined to do the checkout ?

Comment: I am configuring project from local on mac.. project is already  checked out from git on mac.. All permission are correct

Comment: If you work with jenkins you have to work inside Jenkins and not on your machine..To work in Jenkins you need to let Jenkins checkout the code and work with it...otherwise it does not make sense..If you like to build your project on your machine simply use the command like `mvn clean verify`...and Jenkins...

Answer (score 1):

[image]I hope you are using maven project

If your using **windows** machine path somting like this--> `C:\var\www\hello\complete\pom.xml`

or you can get this type also --> `C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\hello-world\complete\pom.xml`

If your using **linux** machine path should be like this --> `/etc/maven/complete/pom.xml` inside **complete** directory pom.xml file should be there

If you are using **git hub** project path should like this --> `https://github.com/username/hello/maven/complete/pom.xml`  inside that directory you should having pom.xml file

then Jenkins will accept peacefully

> make sure you added ***pom.xml*** at the end of path otherwise you will get below error

[image: if you add only path without pom.xml]

Comment: Yes.. I am using maven project. My machine is Mac with operating system High Sierra..

Comment: try to add pom.xml at the end of the path

Comment: Exception . "No such file: ‘/etc//Users/XXX/Documents/WorkSpace/project-automationtesting/pom.xml’"

Comment: Don't use double slash in path ever !!
after /etc there is a double slash (//)

Comment: RROR: No such file /etc/Users/xxx/Documents/WorkSpace/project-automationtesting/pom.xml
Perhaps you need to specify the correct POM file path in the project configuration?  Same error

Comment: Try to run this command -->
chmod +x /etc/Users/xxx/Documents/WorkSpace/project-automationtesting/pom.xml



Then add a path..



if still not working please change the file permission